# ASP.NET routing w/ changing article name

Tags: .net, routes, seo, url-routing

Is it possible to ignore the second last part of an url with ASP.NET routing?

e.g. ../article-name-x/123456/

No matter how the product name changes, we would like to point to the same article always by adding the article id at the end and use that to point to the correct article.

We sometimes have a product that hasn't got it's final name yet on announcement, so we need to update when the final name is known.  But we used the initial url already in our communication and we don't want the link to be broken later.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right you want the route to have both article *name* and *id*.

You can use `Attribute routing` in `.net MVC`. Pass both name and id as path parameters defined in your route. Then in the action you can use any one of them (or both) to search the article.

First allow attribute routing in `RegisterRoutes` method

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Then define a `Route` attribute for your action

```
[RoutePrefix("articles")]
[Route("{action=index}")]
public class ArticlesController : Controller
{
    // e.g /articles
    public ActionResult Index() { … } 

    // e.g. /articles/my-article-name/my-article-id
    [Route("{name}/{id}")]
    public ActionResult Search(string name, string id) { … }
}
```

This action can be called as

```
articles/my-article-name/my-article-id
```

Please refer [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) for details.

HTH.

Comment: Attribute routing seems to be the solution, thanks.  In our case it would be Search(string id) and the name can change to whatever it wants.  E.g.  ../article-name-x/123 and ../article-name-abcdefge/123 should both point to article with id 123